# Why is the letters M and T are similar in hand writing in Russian language?

Tags: буквы

Why is the letters M and T (`м` and `m`) are similar in hand writing in Russian language?

For example: от → *оm*. vs. *oм*

Comment: М and т are not similar at all.

Comment: от → оm. vs. oм.  м and m looks very similiar in Russian handwriting even though they're 2 totaly different consonants (m and t).

Comment: @Influx No they don't. Russian handwriting т is similar to English "m".  But Russian handwriting м looks very different.

Comment: I found the same question with answers in the link above. Thank you.